# nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Sorry, but no matter what I try, there are always error messages?

I have no idea, what is wrong with my file?

---nginx.conf---

```html
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;

}

location / {

        client_max_body_size 2024M;
}

http {

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
 client_max_body_size 2024M;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 
 server {

       client_max_body_size 2024M;
    }
}

# override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

Who can help me so I understand where my mistake is?

I'm trying "client_max_body_size 2024M;" to integrate (html / server / location).

Thank you all!

Comment: You must not put location block out of http block.

Comment: Thank you @Light.G , but If I put everything in the html block, comes also an error message?

nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.cond:50
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Then go with this error message: having a look at 50th line in nginx.conf. It never lie about error.

Comment: In line 50 stands:

 location / {

Comment: location should be in server block.

Comment: Many Thanks! It works now. Sometimes you can not see the forest because of all the trees.

Comment: Again I have a short question: Can I integrate the same changes in /etc/init.d/nginx? Because I get an error message "413 Request Entity Too Large".

Comment: I guess you would like to post video files to server? And you're doing this through a single blocking request?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have a script (similar to youtube) on my Dedicated root server, but I can not upload large video files. I become the error message "413 Request Entity Too Large nginx". The programmer has written a php file, which directly displays the error message.

Comment: Please post another question with specific description about your issue. That would make more experienced people pay attention on it, since not everyone would take time to check comments while you put more question under another.